# Where can I get jsde_sdk.jar for ArcSDE 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, geonetwork

I had an environment working with no problems, with `Geonetwork` `harvesting` metadata from `ArcSDE` *9.3*. It was done trhu the following libraries, copied from the ArcSDE installation to the Geonerwork `lib` dir:

- `jsde_sdk.jar`
- `jpe_sdk.jar`
- `concurrent.jar`
- `icu4_3_2.jar`

After upgrading to `ArcSDE`*10*, the harvesting stopped working.

It is certainly because I'm using `*.jar`s for version *9.3*, while having a *v10* `ArcSDE`, but the new installation doesn't have those `jar`s.

Does anyone knows where to get them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll get it along with the [Java Development kit](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//0001000003v8000000). Found this on the [ArcGIS Resource Center](http://help.arcgis.com/en/geodatabase/10.0/sdk/arcsde/api/japi/japi.htm):

> During ArcSDE client installation, the following files are installed:
>
> - jsde_sdk.jar - Contains the ArcSDE Client, and Geometry Java API class files.
> - jpe_sdk.jar  - Contains the ArcSDE Projection Engine Java API class files.
> - concurrent.jar - Provides standardized, efficient versions of utility classes --commonly encountered in concurrent Java programming.
> - icu4j_3_2.jar - ICU4J libraries required for globalization.

And for building applications:

> To build applications with the ArcSDE Java API, users must have Java
>   Development Kit version 6 or higher installed on your system. You must
>   also add the jsde_sdk.jar, jpe_sdk.jar, concurrent.jar, and
>   icu4j_3_2.jar files to your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Oh. So it seems ESRI has made the life easier by adding a downloadable plug-in for Eclipse and, funny enough, it made it more difficult for me.

Comment: You win some, you lose some ;-)

Comment: I couldn't make it work. Following the steps from [this link](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//0001000003v8000000), I couldn't find the directory `%ARCGISHOME%/java/tools/eclipse_plugin/arcgis_update_site/engine`. I only have `%ARCGISHOME%/java/tools/eclipse_plugin/arcgis_update_site/arcobjects`.

Comment: Best to ask it in another question. That way, people with the same problem will benefit as well. Your original question has been answered, hasn't it?

Comment: You asked where. The how belongs to another question. :-P Why don't you create the directory btw?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6535/discussion-between-r-k-and-j-a-i-l)

Answer (score 0):

According to ESRI Hotline, there is something like a DVD "ArcSDE 10.2 Software Developer Kit English Install Media - Version 10.2". One have to order it separately for some reason and wait until they send it by post. Unfortunately the DVD for the 10.2 version is at this moment not available and they also don't know when it will be, quite ridiculous. Somehow ESRI is very concerned about those jars...