# Installing ArcSDE engine plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, java, plugins, eclipse

I'm looking for the following `jar`s for the ArcSDE API:

- `jsde_sdk.jar`
- `jpe_sdk.jar`
- `concurrent.jar`
- `icu4_3_2.jar`

thanks to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42345/13118) I've found that they [can be gotten installing the ArcSDE `engine` plugin for Eclipse](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#//0001000003v8000000).

But on ESRI's help page it calls for the following directory:

```
%ARCGISHOME%/java/tools/eclipse_plugin/arcgis_update_site/engine
```

My installation, instead, only has the following one:

```
%ARCGISHOME%/java/tools/eclipse_plugin/arcgis_update_site/arcobjects
```

That is, the `arc Objects plugin`, instead of the `engine plugin`.

Where (or how) can I get the ArcSDE `engine` plugin for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that you need to [install ArcGIS Engine](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/java_ao_adf/conceptualhelp/engine/index.html#/Installation/000100000485000000/) first. Once you've done so, you can continue with installing the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: That link calls for the following directory: `%ARCGISHOME%/java/tools/eclipse_plugin/arcgis_update_site/engine`, which, as I stated in the question, don't have in my computer.

Comment: Sorry. Added the wrong link. Updated it now.